# We are seeing some instructions in the object which is generating exceptions

Tags: c, compilation, powerpc

Memset & array assignments lead to instructions that is causing exception in power pc architecture.

Example:

```
uint32        xy_null_entry[SOC_MAX_MEM_WORDS] = {0};
```

or `memset()` library function is resulting in below instruction:

```
vxor vr0,vr0,vr0
```

Tried compiler options `-fno-builtin`, `-mabi=no-spe`, `-mabi=no-altivec` but it didnt help the ELF file when disassembled (`objdump -d <*.elf>`) still contains these instructions. How to avoid this?  Are there any compiler options with which I can overcome this?

Comment: It's possible that the compiler is emitting a call to `memset()` for your big array of zeroes, and that `memset()` is in a library compiled with the wrong flags. You should check the target of your runtime libraries.

Comment: Is there a way to check which was flags the current libraries were compiled with ?

Comment: Just to clarify: when you refer to `objdump -d <*.elf>`, is this .elf file a statically linked binary? or is it dynamically linked (and so should not contain any instructions provided by your libraries)?

Comment: Its statically linked. The other observation i am seeing now is that when we put -fno-builtin, -mabi=no-spe, -mabi=no-altivec in the compile option the instructions emitted due to memset invocation is gone but the one due array assignments are still present. This is gone only when we remove the optimization flag from the compile option (-O1 , -O). But we need to retain the optimization level without these instruction in the object file.

Comment: OK, can you post the full compiler command?